# Develop android app using Navigation Drawer in Android Studio

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I'm using android studio 1.1.0 to develop an app with navigation drawer activity. To develop this app I [refer this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwqzhY5i2rc) video in you tube.

when I create `objFragment` it automatically convert as  `android.app.Fragment objFragment = null;` But in video it show as `Fragment objFragment = null;`
At the 6.00 min of the video it replace `placeHolderFragment(position +1)` with `objFragment` which is created before. When doing this I got the following error.
[image]

How can I fixed this error.

Comment: Declare **objFragment** as `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the answer.

I replace

```
android.app.Fragment objFragment = null
```

by

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment objFragment = null
```

and `import android.app.Fragment;` by `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in all the java class files.